# Sort dict by key as a list, without list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary whose keys are also in a list.
I need to get the values, in a way that there keys are sorted in the same order than the list (knowing that all keys are in the list, once only)

A simple way to achieve this is to use a list comprehension:

```
[mydict[myID] for myID in allID]
```

with allID being the list that we want to sort accordingly.

However this code is too slow. Performance is critical in my code.

Is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: Can you post details on why this code is slow?

Comment: what about using `OrderedDict` in the first place? Or python 3.6

Comment: Just because I need to run it millions of times

Comment: Using ordered dict is even slower unfortunately. Python 3.6 is not available where I work... Stuck with 3.3 for now

Comment: A minimal example of the data would not hurt here

Comment: even with sorted dict I don't think that would be faster.

Comment: Sorting a list a million times sounds like a problem. Can you describe the use case in more detail as to why you need to do this. Maybe we're dealing with an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/136323) here.

Comment: do you really need to recreate a list with the lists? or just iterate?

Comment: I need to make a np.array out of it. This is a weight dictionary: I need to have it sorted to multiply it with a correlation matrix (so indices must match). Depending on the output of my function, I loop through it and changes the weights of some of the keys in the dict

Comment: Agree with @TimPietzcker: probably we need a bit more info to know how we can optimise your code! For example: why is it a dictionary and not already a (sorted) numpy array? How many weights do you change each iteration?

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to help you unless you do a better job of explaining your problem. Why exactly do you need to sort the list more than once?